# Javascript: writing wrong value on innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take a value from a readonly input (which value is also generated via javascript), adding to another readonly input and then print it.
Here's the html code:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="importounitario1" name="importounitario1" style="width:80px;" onchange="CalcolaImportoParziale1()">
```

The readonly input where the javascript gonna take the value.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="importoparziale1" name="importoparziale1" style="width:80px;" readonly="true" placeholder="" value="">
```

And here's the Javascript code

```
function CalcolaImportoParziale1() {
    if (document.getElementById("da1").value && document.getElementById("a1").value && document.getElementById("importounitario1").value) {
        var numeroiniziale  = document.getElementById("da1").value;
        var numerofinale    = document.getElementById("a1").value;
        var importounitario = document.getElementById("importounitario1").value;
        var quantita        = (numerofinale-numeroiniziale) + 1;
        var importoparziale = importounitario * quantita;

        document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value       = importoparziale;
        document.getElementById("importoparziale1").placeholder = importoparziale;

        if (document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value && document.getElementById("importoparziale2").value && document.getElementById("importoparziale3").value && document.getElementById("importoparziale4").value && document.getElementById("importoparziale5").value) {
            var importototale = document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value + document.getElementById("importoparziale2").value + document.getElementById("importoparziale3").value + document.getElementById("importoparziale4").value + document.getElementById("importoparziale5").value;
            document.getElementById("importototalelordo").value         = importototale;
            document.getElementById("importototalelordo").placeholder   = importototale;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value && document.getElementById("importoparziale2").value && document.getElementById("importoparziale3").value && document.getElementById("importoparziale4").value) {
            var importototale = document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value + document.getElementById("importoparziale2").value + document.getElementById("importoparziale3").value + document.getElementById("importoparziale4").value;
            document.getElementById("importototalelordo").value         = importototale;
            document.getElementById("importototalelordo").placeholder   = importototale;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value && document.getElementById("importoparziale2").value && document.getElementById("importoparziale3").value) {
            var importototale = document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value + document.getElementById("importoparziale2").value + document.getElementById("importoparziale3").value;
            document.getElementById("importototalelordo").value         = importototale;
            document.getElementById("importototalelordo").placeholder   = importototale;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value && document.getElementById("importoparziale2").value) {
            var importototale = document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value + document.getElementById("importoparziale2").value;
            document.getElementById("importototalelordo").value         = importototale;
            document.getElementById("importototalelordo").placeholder   = importototale;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value) {
            document.getElementById("importototalelordo").value         = document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value;
            document.getElementById("importototalelordo").placeholder   = document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value;
        }

        var quantitaparziale1   = document.getElementById("a1").value - document.getElementById("da1").value;
        var quantitaparziale2   = document.getElementById("a2").value - document.getElementById("da2").value;
        var quantitaparziale3   = document.getElementById("a3").value - document.getElementById("da3").value;
        var quantitaparziale4   = document.getElementById("a4").value - document.getElementById("da4").value;
        var quantitaparziale5   = document.getElementById("a5").value - document.getElementById("da5").value;
        var quantitatotale      = quantitaparziale1 + quantitaparziale2 + quantitaparziale3 + quantitaparziale4 + quantitaparziale5;
        document.getElementById("quantitatotale").value         = quantitatotale;
        document.getElementById("quantitatotale").placeholder   = quantitatotale;
    }
}
```

Since there are 5 input fields, there are 5 functions named like 'CalcolaImportoParziale2'. Right now the code print on ImportoTotale literally a number + number, dealing with the number like strings instead.

Comment: Notice, that the value of an input element is _always_  a string, even despite of `type="number"`. Automatic coersion usually takes care of this, but you will get troubles, when trying to do increments with strings, since strings are concatenated with `+` operator too. Convert input values to numbers before doing math with them.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Teemu got my problem: right now my code is not working since what i got on Importototale is not the added number but literally the number + number. So what would be the right code to convert the string in a number?

Comment: That should be easy to search, on web or here at SO. To reduce your code to a single function, you could pass a number indicating the last character in `id`s, then just concatenate the argument with the body of the id in `gEBI`s.

Comment: This code block hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

don't quite under stand your question so i just follow it literally that

> I'm trying to take a value from a readonly input (which value is also generated via javascript), adding to another readonly input and then print it.

```js
document.getElementById('secondValue').value = document.getElementById('firstValue').value;
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =document.getElementById('secondValue').value;
```

```html
<input id="firstValue" type="text" value="apple" readonly/>
<input id="secondValue" type="text" value="" readonly/>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Convert input values to numbers before doing math with them.

Thanks to Teemo answer i sorted it out: since the problem was Javascript took the value as a string, i resolved using the `Number()` function, using it like this:

```
Number(var importototale = document.getElementById("importoparziale1").value)
```

Thanks everybody and sorry for my horrible code.